# How to filter the 5 letter string after certain keyword and return as an array using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

How to filter the 5 letter string after certain keyword which occurs every time in the string and return as an array using Javascript?

**Example string:** `My secret code is 12345 and his secret code is 67890`

So from the above example, return 5 characters next to the keyword- **secret code is**. So, I need "12345" and "67890" in an array which is after the keyword- **secret code is**.

**Expected Output:** `["12345", "67890"]`

Comment: The next 5 characters after *secret code* are actually ` is 1`

Comment: ` is 1` is the first 5 characters after `secret code`

Comment: But... if youre looking for the first 5 digits after `secret code` google/look on stack overflow for the regex of how to find digits in a string. The answers are out there.

Comment: Sorry guys, I have edited the post now.

Comment: @Craicerjack - Sorry man, I have just edited the post. Can you help me now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function getCodes(str) {
  return str.match(/(?<=secret code is ).{5}/g)
}
getCodes("My secret code is 12345 and his secret code is 67890")
// will return array ["12345", "67890"]
```

Edit: with RegExp-save keyword

```js
function getCodes(str, keyword) {
  keyword = keyword.replace(/([^a-zA-Z0-9 ])/g, '\\$1');
  return str.match(new RegExp('(?<=' + keyword + ').{5}', 'g'))
}
getCodes("My secret code is 12345 and his secret code is 67890", "secret code is ")
// will return array ["12345", "67890"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
s.match(new RegExp(`${keyword}.{5}`,'g')).map(x=>x.substr(-5))
```

```js
s="My secret code is 12345 and his secret code is 54321"
keyword="secret code is ";

m = s.match(new RegExp(`${keyword}.{5}`,'g')).map(x=>x.substr(-5))

console.log(m);
```

the `keyword` should have escaped regexp special characters - more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3561493/860099)

Comment: **Warning:** This code is buggy, because RegExp special chars are not escaped!